# Recording form input on a server without php/asp

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a small project to record some form input on a page that's hosted on a bare bones Network Solutions account with no server-side scripting.  I've been trying to research solutions and it seems the only way to do this is maybe by using a secondary account on a host that DOES have php and submit to it via ajax (I don't want the page to refresh so I'm assuming this would be necessary).  I've never used ajax before and this project is due very soon so I'm looking for examples or solutions online that don't require a big learning curve.  Can anyone suggest any resources?

Comment: If you do not have access to any type of server side scripting language how do you expect to save the data to the server? Even if you got another server that allowed you, you would still only be able to save the data to that server, unless you could upload the file via FTP to the main server. Other than that, yea this task is not really possible without some server side scripting language backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the page to refresh the only method is to make the form post into an 0x0 pixels iframe as ajax doesn't work cross-sites.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form action="http://www.example.org/otherHost.php" .... target="myIframe">
        .....
    </form>
    <iframe src="someblankdocument.html" name="myIframe" id="myIframe" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

"recording" to a file is as easy as

```
file_put_contents( $file, $data );
```

if you install jquery making a post request to your php page is as easy as

```
$.post(
    "file.php",
    { data here }
    function(data) {
        alert("success");
    }
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

http://www.php.net/file_put_contents

If you want to put your data in a database it gets more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

1. You **must** use server-side processing to store form result from users.
2. You **don't** need to use ajax to submit form to another account or location.

e.g. For example if you have two accounts `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com`

In `foo.example.com/index.html` you can have a form that submit to `bar.example.com`:

```
<form action='bar.example.com/saveForm.php' method='post'>
   ...
</form>
```

And here is a very simple saveForm.php that save result to `bar.example.org/data.csv`, without validating the input:

```
<?php

$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'a');
fputcsv($fp, $_POST);
fclose($fp);

// Tell user then you got their data - normally should do error checking first
echo "Data saved. Thank you!";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up having to alter it slightly as I only had one form field and so it wasn't inserting commas, but thanks for the rudimentary and very easy php to get started!